# shinyjs::toggleState does not work with input produced in renderUI

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

In the following app, users are supposed to upload a `csv` dataset file and select a column for further processing. The columns to choose from will of course depend on the uploaded file. Therefore, the dropdown that implements the choices is dynamically generated via `renderUI`.

I want to use `shinyjs::toggleState` to disable the dropdown menu until the dataset is actually uploaded. Unfortunately, this does not work. Does somebody know why and/or has a workaraound?

Many thanks!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  fileInput("file", "Choose a File"),
  uiOutput("select")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  dataset <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$file))
      NULL
    else
      read.csv(input$file$datapath)
  })
  output$select <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(dataset()))
      choices <- "this should not be selectable!"
    else
      choices <- colnames(dataset())
    selectizeInput("choose", "Choose a Column", choices=choices)
  })
  observe({
    toggleState("choose", !is.null(dataset()))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  fileInput("file", "Choose a File"),
  uiOutput("select")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  dataset <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$file))
      NULL
    else
      read.csv(input$file$datapath)
  })
  output$select <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(dataset()))
      choices <- "this should not be selectable!"
    else
      choices <- colnames(dataset())
    selectizeInput("choose", "Choose a Column", choices=choices)
  })
  observe({
    req(input$choose)
    toggleState("choose", !is.null(dataset()))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. In my usecase, it is indeed required that the dropdown is shown also when there is no dataset yet. Also, it would be interesting to know why this fails.

Comment: okay that's doable- please check updated code. You just need to wait for selectizeinput to be rendered before toggling it- right now it's trying to toggle what doesn't exist on UI I believe. if you add a req(input$choose) to your observe, it should work

Comment: thank you for updating the snippet! `req` does the job in this case. I will accept your answer soon unless some other person provides more details.